# Split the content in the list to required output

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7

I am working on a personal project and I am stuck at a point. Any suggestion is appreciated

My input is this

```
>>> mylist = ["'(select envrnmnt_parm_value from envrnmnt_parm where module_nm='Global')||home/inbound/travel/IMS/'"]
```

My required output is this

```
"INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (app_s3) VALUES ((select envrnmnt_parm_value from envrnmnt_parm where module_nm='Global')||'home/inbound/travel/IMS/')"
```

I have removed the unnecessary portions from the statements and keeping it short just to make my question clear. I hope it's understandable. I have tried multiple approaches but I am not getting the required result.

One such thing I have tried is -

```
>>> 'INSERT INTO (app_s3) VALUES ({})'.format(','.join(mylist))
"INSERT INTO (app_s3) VALUES ('(select envrnmnt_parm_value from envrnmnt_parm where module_nm='Global')||home/inbound/travel/IMS/')"
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first `myList` to:

```
mylist = ["(select envrnmnt_parm_value from envrnmnt_parm where module_nm='Global')"+ '||' + '\'home/inbound/travel/IMS/\'']
```

- Here in the third one I have added two `'` and escaped them using `\`.

Comment: Apologies, I had done a mistake while writing my question description. I have changed the mylist. Now it has two double quotes and 1 single quote. Can you provide a solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the single quotes from both ends and then split from '||' into two strings.

Here is my way of implementation.

```
>>> first, second = mylist[0][1:-1].split('||')
>>> f'INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (app_s3) VALUES ({first}||{second})'
"INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (app_s3) VALUES ((select envrnmnt_parm_value from envrnmnt_parm where module_nm='Global')||home/inbound/travel/IMS/)"
```